# how to set page load timeout on firefox web driver in java when using from selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, d, page-load-time

I used :

```
url ="https://superuser.com/questions/113219/go-back-to-previous-directory-in-shell"
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(url);
```

but it's don't work:
Website takes around 18 to 20 seconds to load but I don't get any exception.

**Shouldn't I get TimedoutException in above case?**

how can I set timeout on load the page?
NOTE: I want change page load timeout in different point of my program.

> Webdriver Version: 3.4.0
>
> Firefox Version: 50
>
> gecko driver 0.11.0(or 0.18.0)

Comment: You need to give more information. What *but it's don't work* means? What is the Selenium version you are using?

Comment: are you using selenium 3 ?

Comment: I user selenium 3.4.0 and firefox 50 and gecko driver 0.11.0(or 0.18.0). but don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use old version selenium and firefox :
selenium 2.53.0
firefox 45
without gecko driver